# Is there a library to generate API calls based on OpenApiDocument?

Tags: c#, openapi

I have a swagger JSON from a stream

```
OpenApiDocument swaggerJson = new OpenApiStreamReader().Read(stream, outOpenApiDiagnostic diag);
```

`swaggerJson` contains nested key-value pairs, like "Paths" containing possible Operations like "Get" which contain possible parameters, along with their "required", "minimum" and "maximum" properties.

**Is there an easy way to generate list of API requests as strings**, composed of endpoints and permutations of it's request parameters and their values based on max/min?

Example strings on generated lists:

```
/endpoint_name?/<required_param1>=<min_value>&<required_param2>=<min_value>
/endpoint_name?/<required_param1>=<min_value>&<required_param2>=<max_value>
/endpoint_name?/<required_param1>=<max_value>&<required_param2>=<min_value>
/endpoint_name?/<required_param1>=<max_value>&<required_param2>=<max_value>
```

and rest of possible combinations: string from above + permutations of all optional

I mean something dedicated strictly to API requests. Some smart library that would compose list of all possible positive requests as an argument for nunit test?

```
[TestCaseSource(nameof(GenerateGetPositiveRequests))]
    public void TestGetPositive(string request)
    {
        var expectedStatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
        var responseStatusCode = TestFunctions.GetResponse(request).StatusCode;
    
        Assert.That(responseStatusCode, Is.EqualTo(expectedStatusCode));
    }
```

Possibly I can do that simply creating permutations of strings based on lists?

Comment: I don't think there's a library that does that in C# for nUnit tests atm. I would just generate the C# Client from the spec and writing the tests unless we're talking thousands of endpoints. Regardless of that, maybe this is relevant: https://docs.stepci.com/import/openapi.html